# Hide community page from showing in Google searches

Tags: community

So my question is very simple! I want to hide my community page from appearing in the search engine Google, I am sure it's somewhere in the configurations of the experience builder of the page but still can't figure out exactly when!

does anybody know where or how i can do that ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make your site/community public, search engines can then index all the pages of your site. So, if you don’t want search engines like Google to index certain pages, you can:

- [Make a page private](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_prop.htm&type=5) : Use this method to make the page unavailable to both guest users and search engines.
- [Use the noindex meta tag](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo_tags.htm&type=5) :This tag prevents search engines from showing the page in search results, but allows guest users to view the page.
- [Create a custom robots.txt file](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_seo_configure.htm&type=5) :The robots.txt file is a rules-based approach to control the visibility of specific areas of your site to search engines. Guest users can still view pages that you don’t want indexed.

By default, objects displayed on a page are private and can’t be indexed until you explicitly [make an object and its associated fields available to search engines.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo_object_access.htm&type=5)